# Animation with mat in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I've been told that you can make games and animations with the class mat in openCV, but I've been trying for hours and I can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried to make still images where I copy matrices of images into a single image, which works perfectly, but it can't be used for animation or games. Now I'm trying to use a window (which I think will be more interactive), but I can only show one image at a time and the matrices of the tower can't be added to the window without crashing.

This is code where I try to copy the tower pixels to the window, but it fills out the window with the pixels of the tower. I've also tried to use rowRange like this `tower.copyTo(window.rowRange(375, 425).colRange(225, 275));` but it crashes.

```
int widthWindow = 1600;
int heightWindow = 800;

Mat window, tower;    
tower = Mat::zeros(Size(50, 50), CV_8UC1);

//Creating the window  
namedWindow("Window", WINDOW_NORMAL);  
resizeWindow("Window", widthWindow, heightWindow);  

//Graphics   
rectangle(tower, Point(0, 0), Point(50, 50), Scalar(255), -1, 8, 0); //Draw of the Tower
tower.copyTo(window);

//Show Image
imshow("Window",window);
```

Are there any solutions how to make a game or an animation with mat in openCV?

Best Regards
Kasper

Comment: OpenCV has a very limited GUI functionalities, which are mainly used for debugging purposes only.

Comment: Whoever recommended you to do this was **really wrong**. You'd better use other libraries such as Qt for GUI stuff or, better, use Unity. You _can_ do this with OpenCV, but it'll extremely cumbersome. OpenCV is not the right tool for this

Comment: Maybe look at SDL https://www.libsdl.org

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is measurement and analysis tool, not a renderer. I would reccomend you to use OpenGL, Unity or DirectX. As mentioned in comments OpenCV has poor GUI and rendering capabilities